# How to make WordPress forms secure (HTTPS)

Tags: forms, https

I've been trying to get my site to run over HTTPS for ages. At the moment (in Chrome) I have the padlock but have the yellow triangle over it because some content is insecure. I check out the console and it's the forms inside WordPress, specifically the search forms in the black admin bar and in the sidebar.

I'd like to keep the search bars but I'd like to know how to make them secure as I've searched around and no one seems to be having this issue but me? Can I get some assistance please, I'm starting from scratch on this so any code is welcome!

Comment: I've found out that the reason I had insecure content was due to my search forms and the action url they were using. I changed both forms (searchform.php in theme and admin-bar.php in wp-includes) to https://... however the admin-bar search form refuses to update itself for some reason. So just 1 insecure content warning now.

Comment: what have you tried? do you just try to access the site over https without doing any code changes to support it?

Comment: When switching to HTTPS, did you run a search-and-replace for http://example.org to https://example.org throughout your entire database, and specifically the home and siteurl options? WordPress should pick that up automatically if you did.